# Replace special characters in XSLT

Tags: xslt, string

I want to remove characters other than alphabets from a string in XSLT. For example

```
<Name>O'Niel</Name> = <Name>ONiel</Name>
<Name>St Peter</Name> = <Name>StPeter</Name>
<Name>A.David</Name> = <Name>ADavid</Name>
```

Can we use Regular Expression in XSLT to do this? Which is right way to implement this?

EDIT: This needs to done on XSLT 1.0.

Comment: check my answer how to do it without RegExp, which aren't supported in XSLT/XPath 1.0 by the way.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is a pure XSLT way to do this.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vAllowedSymbols"
        select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="
            translate(
                .,
                translate(., $vAllowedSymbols, ''),
                ''
                )
            "/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result against this sample:

```
<t>
    <Name>O'Niel</Name>
    <Name>St Peter</Name>
    <Name>A.David</Name>
</t>
```

Will be:

```
<t>
    <Name>ONiel</Name>
    <Name>StPeter</Name>
    <Name>ADavid</Name>
</t>
```

Comment: @Flack - This is great. My solution was useful for replacing single characters in a blacklist with any other sequence of characters, but `translate` is a much better solution for applying a whitelist or simple one-to-one replacements.

Comment: @lwburk. You can use `translate` for "blacklist" also. It would be even simplier. No need for recursion when you don't need "string to another string" replace.

Comment: How to apply this template for a Node like this /Application/Contact/FirstName?

Comment: @Amzath. You can basically use XPath Expr starting with `translate` whenever you take string-values of nodes and attributes.

Comment: @Flack - Right, that's part of what I was trying to say, which is ultimately why I deleted my post. You need the recursion approach in XSLT 1.0 for doing more complicated replacements, but it was complete overkill in this case.

Comment: How to i add ' (apostrophe) as a allowed special character?

Answer (score 14):

Here's a 2.0 option:

**EDIT: Sorry...the 1.0 requirement was added after I started on my answer.**

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doc>
  <Name>O'Niel</Name>
  <Name>St Peter</Name>
  <Name>A.David</Name>
</doc>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="*|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(.,'[^a-zA-Z]','')"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doc>
   <Name>ONiel</Name>
   <Name>StPeter</Name>
   <Name>ADavid</Name>
</doc>
```

Here are a couple more ways of using [`replace()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xpath-functions-20101214/#func-replace)...

Using "i" (case-insensitive mode) [flag](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xpath-functions-20101214/#flags):

```
replace(.,'[^A-Z]','','i')
```

Using [category escapes](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#charcter-classes):

```
replace(.,'\P{L}','')
```

Answer (score 3):

I just created a function based on the code in this example...

```
    <xsl:function name="lancet:stripSpecialChars">
    <xsl:param name="string" />
    <xsl:variable name="AllowedSymbols" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789()*%$#@!~&lt;&gt;,.?[]=- +   /\ '"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="
        translate(
            $string,
            translate($string, $AllowedSymbols, ''),
            ' ')
        "/>
</xsl:function>
```

and an example of the usage would be as follows:

```
<xsl:value-of select="lancet:stripSpecialChars($string)"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

quickest way is `<xsl:value-of select="translate(Name,translate(Name,'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',''),'')" />`

the inner translate removes the alphabets (the needed characters). The result of that translate leaves other characters. the outer translate removes those unwanted characters