# How to write xslt if element contains letters?

Tags: regex, xslt

Sth should be all letters or in regular expressions [A-Z]. How to combine xslt with regular expressions?

```
 <xsl:if test="string-contains(//ns0:elem/value, 'sth')">


        </xsl:if>
```

Comment: @_marko: Did you read my answer and was it useful to you?

Comment: I just updated the answer with a second XPath expression and a complete code example that demonstrates both of these XPath 1.0 expressions -- the first using the *double-translate* method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

XPath/XSLT 1.0 does not support regular expressions, but simple validation can be performed using the basic string functions.

**Whitelisting**

The XPath 1.0 `translate` function can be used to simulate a whitelist:

```
<xsl:variable name="alpha" 
              select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>
<xsl:if test="string-length(translate(., $alpha, '')) &gt; 0">
    <!-- context node contains non-alpha characters -->
</xsl:if>
```

The test uses `translate` to first remove all upper- and lower-case letters. If the resulting string's length is non-zero, then the original string must have contained additional characters.

Note that the expression above could be simplified to:

```
<xsl:if test="translate(., $alpha, '')">
```

... because any non-empty string evaluates to true.

**Blacklisting**

Use the double-translate method to treat `$alpha` as a blacklist:

```
<xsl:if test="translate(., translate(., $alpha, ''), '')">
    <!-- context-node contains characters on the blacklist (in $alpha) -->
</xsl:if>
```

The inner `translate` returns a string with all its alpha characters removed, which is then used as the template to the second `translate` call, resulting in a string containing only the alpha characters. If this string is non-zero, then we found a character on the blacklist. This is a classic approach. See, for example, this previous question on SO:

- [Replace special characters in XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084065/replace-special-characters-in-xslt)

A blacklist test could also be performed like this:

```
not(string-length(translate(., $alpha, ''))=string-length())
```

If the length of the string after removing all of the blacklisted characters is not equal to the length of the original string, then the string must have contained a character on the blacklist.

**Summary**

Blacklists and whitelists are really two sides of the same coin. The following demonstrates their usage together:

```
<xsl:if test="translate(., $alpha, '')">
    [contains some characters not on the list]
</xsl:if> 
<xsl:if test="not(translate(., $alpha, ''))">
    [contains only characters on the list]
</xsl:if> 
<xsl:if test="translate(., translate(., $alpha, ''), '')">
    [contains some characters on the list]
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="not(translate(., translate(., $alpha, ''), ''))">
    [contains only characters not on the list]
</xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 2):

In XPath 1.0 (works with XSLT 1.0), you don't have tool for regex (you just have functions like `contains` or `starts-with`, see link below for more information)

In XPATH 2.0 (works with XSLT 2.0), you've got the `matches` function and the `replace` function (see link below).

URL  to see :

XPath 1.0 string functions : http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-String-Functions

XPath 2.0 regex functions : http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#string.match

Comment: I've got a solution and are using version 1.0. How to search for letters in a string if you can't use regex in xslt?

Answer (score 2):

> How to search for letters in a string if you can't use regex in xslt?

Good question, +1.

**Use**:

```
translate(., translate(., $vAlpha, ''), '')
```

**This produces all characters in the string value of the current node, that** *are* **in `$vAlpha`**

**In case you want to see if a given string `$str` contains only letters and no other character, use**:

```
string-length(translate($str, $vAlpha, '')) = 0
```

**A complete code example**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vUpper" select=
  "'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vLower" select=
  "'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vAlpha" select=
      "concat($vUpper, $vLower)"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vStr" select="'A12B_..c02d'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select=
    "translate($vStr,
               translate($vStr, $vAlpha, ''), '')
    "/>


    The string <xsl:value-of select="$vStr"/> has <xsl:text/>
    <xsl:value-of select=
    "string-length(translate($vStr, $vAlpha, ''))"/> <xsl:text/>
    non-letters

 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on any XML document (not used), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
ABcd


    The string A12B_..c02d has 7
    non-letters
```

**Remember**: The first XPath expression above demonstrates the so called "*double-translate method*", first proposed by @Michael Kay.