# How do I use a regular expression in XSLT 1.0?

Tags: regex, xslt

I am using XSLT 1.0.
My input information may contain these values

```
<!--case 1-->
<attribute>123-00</attribute>

<!--case 2-->
<attribute>Abc-01</attribute>

<!--case 3-->
<attribute>--</attribute>

<!--case 4-->
<attribute>Z2-p01</attribute>
```

I want to find out those string that match the criteria:

```
if string has at least 1 alphabet AND has at least 1 number,
then 
do X processing
else
do Y processing
```

In example above, for case 1,2,4 I should be able to do `X` processing. For case 3, I should be able to do `Y` processing.

I aim to use a regular expression (in XSLT 1.0).

For all the cases, the attribute can take any value of any length.

I tried use of `match`, but the processor returned an error.
I tried use of `translate` function, but not sure if used the right way.

I am thinking about.

```
if String matches [a-zA-Z0-9]* 
then do X processing
else
do y processing.
```

How do I implement that using XSLT 1.0 syntax?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**This solution really works in XSLT 1.0** (and is simpler, because it doesn't and needn't use the double-translate method.):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vUpper" select=
 "'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vLower" select=
 "'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vAlpha" select="concat($vUpper, $vLower)"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vDigits" select=
 "'0123456789'"/>

 <xsl:template match="attribute">
  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test=
    "string-length() != string-length(translate(.,$vAlpha,''))
    and
     string-length() != string-length(translate(.,$vDigits,''))">

    Processing X
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
    Processing Y
   </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML fragment -- made a well-formed XML document**:

```
<t>
    <!--case 1-->
    <attribute>123-00</attribute>
    <!--case 2-->
    <attribute>Abc-01</attribute>
    <!--case 3-->
    <attribute>--</attribute>
    <!--case 4-->
    <attribute>Z2-p01</attribute>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
Processing Y


Processing X

Processing Y


Processing X
```

**Do Note**: Any attempt to use with a true XSLT 1.0 processor code like this (borrowed from another answer to this question) will fail with error:

```
<xsl:template match=
"attribute[
           translate(.,
                     translate(.,
                               concat($upper, $lower),
                               ''),
                     '')
         and
           translate(., translate(., $digit, ''), '')]
 ">
```

because in XSLT 1.0 it is forbidden for a match pattern to contain a variable reference.

Comment: Right, of course, about the match pattern, but double-translate vs. string-length comparison is simply preference/opinion.

Comment: @lwburk: So, you are saying that *double* translate isn't more complex than *single* translate? :)

Comment: @Dimitre - Hehe, well `translate(.,translate(.,$vAlpha,''),'')` is 16 fewer characters than `string-length()!=string-length(translate(.,$vAlpha,''))` and while I'll agree that it looks a little odd, at first, I'm sure you'll agree that it's an easily recognized pattern once you've used it a few times.

Comment: @Dimitre - Plus, the string-length solution has *three* function calls to double-translate's *two* :)

Answer (score 3):

If you found this question because you're looking for a way to use regular expressions in XSLT 1.0, and you're writing an application using Microsoft's XSLT processor, you can solve this problem by using an **inline C# script**.

I've written out an example and a few tips in [**this thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27020359/forcing-xslt-to-use-version-2-with-xslcompiledtransform/39927584#39927584), where someone was seeking out similar functionality.  It's super simple, though it may or may not be appropriate for your purposes.

Answer (score 2):

XSLT *does not support* regular expressions, but you can fake it.

The following stylesheet prints an `X processing` message for all `attribute` elements having a string value containing at least one number *and* at least one letter (and `Y processing` for those that do not):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:variable name="lower" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="upper" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="digit" select="'0123456789'"/>
    <xsl:template match="attribute">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="
                translate(., translate(., concat($upper, $lower), ''), '') and 
                translate(., translate(., $digit, ''), '')">
                <xsl:message>X processing</xsl:message>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:message>Y processing</xsl:message>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note:** You said this:

> In example above, for case 1,2,4 I should be able to do X processing.
>   for case 3, I should be able to do Y processing.

But that conflicts with your requirement, because case 1 *does not* contain a letter. If, on the other hand, you really want to match the equivalent of `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, then use this:

```
translate(., translate(., concat($upper, $lower, $digit), ''), '')
```

...which matches any `attribute` having at least one letter *or* number.

See the following question for more information on using `translate` in this way:

- [How to write xslt if element contains letters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386486/how-to-write-xslt-if-element-contains-letters)

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution doesn't work with a real XSLT 1.0 processor. It would be good if you try an XSLT 1.0 solution with an XSLT 1.0 processor. Of course, this works with an XSLT 2.0 processor, but nobody would write such things in XSLT 2.0.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev is right, of course. In practice, this ends up working in a lot of XSLT 1.0 processors (which is the primary reason this error wasn't obvious to me when I tested my solution) but it is technically forbidden by the spec. In any event, the core of the solution -- the double-translate method -- is valid.

Comment: Moved variable out of match pattern, so that no future visitors are mislead. Thanks to @Dimitre for pointing this out. I'm sure I'll forget again in about a week when yet another XSLT 1.0 processor lets me get away with it.

Comment: @lwburk: I'a just curious: Which XSLT 1.0 processors allow this?

Comment: @Dimitre - It works in RAD's default XSLT processor ("IBM Processor for XSLT 1.0" (Run as... -> XSL Transformation)) and Firefox 9.0.1's built-in XSLT processor, as examples.

Comment: @Dimitre - Just tossed together a Xalan/JAXP example and it worked there, too. In all three of these cases, the use of any other XSLT/XPath 2.0 feature fails, but variables in match patterns are allowed.

Comment: @lwburk: These are all non-compliant XSLT processors -- better not to use them. I am using these compliant XSLT 1.0 processors: Saxon 6.5.x, MSXML3, MSXML4, MSXML6, .NET XslCompiledTransform, .NET XslTransform, XML-SPY (Altova).

Comment: Xalan has always allowed variables in match patterns. They were allowed in many working drafts of XSLT 1.0; the restriction was introduced at a late stage because of worries about circularity, but Xalan (or LotusXSL as it was then) never implemented the restriction.