# How to use regex in xsl

Tags: regex, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have this request coming in xml. Its a CDATA

```
<cmd>
     <![CDATA[HG<><><36.75><0420>< ><HS6011201700446279><><>< >< ><  ><><><  ><><  ><  ><><  ><><  ><>]]>
</cmd>
```

I need to extract HS6011201700446279 from the cdata path.

Following is the regex they gave. How to use this in xsl

```
HG<\\s*><\\s*><.*><.*><.*><[A-Z]{2}(\\d{10,}).*
```

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916208/how-do-i-use-a-regular-expression-in-xslt-1-0

Comment: Why do you have literal `>`s in an xml file? If you really have these characters in an "xml file", your file isn't an xml file and you can't use xslt with it. Otherwise, perhaps you should edit your question and show what exactly contains your file. Actually, your question is totally unclear.

Comment: Actually its CDATA in xml. updated the input xml

Comment: Probably you need to use an extension (like scripts) - there is no regex built-in in xslt 1.0. You could also split the string and process it manually - it's a bit painful in pure xslt 1.0 though.

Comment: Check if your xslt processor support the EXSLT regex library http://exslt.org/regexp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no regex support in XSLT 1.0. Assuming that the sub-string you want is within the 6th "tag" of the given string, you could extract it by calling a recursive named template:

```
<xsl:template match="cmd">
    <result>
        <xsl:call-template name="get-Nth-value">
            <xsl:with-param name="list" select="."/>
            <xsl:with-param name="N" select="6"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="get-Nth-value">
    <xsl:param name="list"/>
    <xsl:param name="N"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="'>&lt;'"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$N = 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($list, $delimiter), $delimiter)"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="contains($list, $delimiter) and $N > 1">
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="get-Nth-value">
                <xsl:with-param name="list" select="substring-after($list, $delimiter)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="N" select="$N - 1"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$delimiter"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: can we use exslt regex?

Comment: If your processor supports it. Which processor will you be using?

Comment: we are using datapower. it supports exslt functions

Comment: Then I suppose you can. At least [the documentation](ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/integration/datapower/library/prod_docs/4Q2008/3.7.2-ExtensionFunctionsCatalog.pdf) says you can. I am not a user myself, so I cannot speak from experience. -- Note that every XSLT 1.0 processor supports **some** EXSLT functions - that doesn't means it supports **all** of them. Regex support in particular is very rare.