# Regex in XLST 1.0

Tags: regex, xslt

Is there a way to use regex in XSLT 1.0 with XML as the input and desired output? I am trying to use a test to confirm that a variable is in a timecode format, i.e. hh:mm:ss:ff.

The regular expression I currently am working with is:

`[0-1][0-9]|2[0-3])(:|;)[0-5][0-9](:|;)[0-5][0-9](:|;)[0-9][0-9]`

To produce a value time code in format hh:mm:ss:ff the following requirements must be met:

```
[hh = 00 - 19 or 20 - 23]
[; or :]
[mm = 00 - 59]
[; or :]
[ss = 00 -59]
[; or :]
[ff = 00 - 99]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use a regular expression in XSLT 1.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916208/how-do-i-use-a-regular-expression-in-xslt-1-0)

Comment: It is slightly like this, however this expression is much more complicated than 1 number and 1 letter. I wanted to use an expression such as: ([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3])(:|;)[0-5][0-9](:|;)[0-5][0-9](:|;)[0-9][0-9](@[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,}){0,1}){0,1}

Comment: The answer, however, is going to be essentially the same as in the previous question.  XSLT 1.0 does not support regular expressions; if your processor supports the EXSLT regular expressions functions (http://exslt.org/regexp/), use them; otherwise, fake it.  The pattern you describe is not that hard to test and process.

Comment: @Parfait Verifying the format of a text string is completely different from trying to *parse* (i.e. separate markup from payload) an XML/HTML document.

Comment: @hguza Which XSLT 1.0 processor are you using?

Comment: I will be importing into Vantage, currently I am testing on sublime text 3. I am not able to use EXSLT or XSLT 2.0

Comment: @hguza I have no idea what Vantage is.See here how to identify the XSLT procesor: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25244370/how-can-i-check-which-xslt-processor-is-being-used-in-solr/25245033#25245033

Comment: Right now I am using Microsoft

Comment: See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb986124.aspx Although I believe the answer given below, which does not require any extensions is simple enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There is no regex support in XSLT 1.0.
2. Your processor *may* offer a way to use regex as an extension.
3. You can easily perform a partial test validating the *format* (but
   not the *contents*) of the variable as:

   ```
   translate($TC, '123456789;', '000000000:') ='00:00:00:00'
   ```

   This will return true for any string formatted as `"##:##:##:##"`
   (where any of the colons can be a semi-colon). However, it will not
   check for the hours being less than 24, or the minutes/seconds being
   less than 60.

   If you want such tests, you will have to add them individually,
   e.g.:

   ```
   substring($TC, 1, 2) &lt; 24
   ```

   for the hours.