# remove escape characters from XML string in java

Tags: java, xml, html-escape-characters

I have inout XML with following format

```
<Some_tag>
   <childTag>this is >25000</childTag>
</Some_tag>
```

the actual XML is very big with +200KB. I am reading this XML in Java. I am getting it as String.

What is solution to remove those > (Special char/escape char) from Tag values?

Comment: The above is invalid XML. `>` should be escaped to `&gt;`. And any XML parser will transform back the escaped `&gt;` to `>`, if that's your question.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  That's well-formed XML as it stands (`<` must be escaped in character content but `>` is legal almost anywhere).

Comment: [documentation on >](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#syntax)

Comment: OK let me put my problem again.. end user is mannuly updating/uploading this XML, now for some tags they add those special char. And I am reading this XML using Java. so need a solution to trasate that <,> to &gt; and &lt;, I did transfer all the elements by replace with regex but did not found solution for this<>.

Comment: Thanks, I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Use XSLT try something like this

[XSLT to remove chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084065/replace-special-characters-in-xslt)

Or use jaxb move all the xml to beans and remove the non needed chars from the String properties.

Comment: let me test the xslt way. The JAXB way is way far for the app I am working. Its all legacy and Compex Schema failed several times to translate to Jaxb

Answer (score 0):

XML should be like

```
&lt;Some_tag&gt;
   &lt;childTag&gt;this is &gt;25000&lt;/childTag&gt;
&lt;/Some_tag&gt;

easy to parse your parser easily convert &lt; to < and &gt; to >
```

Comment: I don't want this **way**

Comment: @CodeDCode  so what you want

Comment: I am getting those escape char in Java String, I need to replace them with &gt; and &lt; before it goes to parser so parser will not fail