# replace the character in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am using the xslt for transformation but from input 240 characters receiving in one element ,In that element different special characters receiving(eg :---> %,?,/,-,_,@,!,$,^) .

I need to replace the those characters.

It is possible in XSLT 1.0.If it is possible can you please give me the code with examples?.Thanks

Eg:

```
<remark> whfwlknf234@skl$ck?nvwkld^fnwlfn </remark>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace special characters in XSLT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084065/replace-special-characters-in-xslt)

Answer (score 1):

> It is possible in XSLT 1.0

Yes, it is possible. Use the [`translate()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-translate) function to replace them with ... oh, you didn't say with what.

Comment: My input xml :
<input>
         <remark>wbhdcb?uish@dc!wdh*uwh</remark>
</input>

Expecting out Put:--->
<output>
     <remark>wbhdcb%?%uish%@%dc'!'wdh'*'uwh<?remark>
</output>

If we will use translate just only one character it will be replaced but in this case instead of ? need to translate to %?% .

If it is possible can u please explain.Thanks.

Comment: @vinod Please don't post code in comments - edit your question instead.